# 404 from server events heartbeat endpoint

Tags: c#, react-native, servicestack

We are recieving proportionately low but consistent 404 from server events from a channel subscription. This seems to only be via our react interface which uses the typescript adapter here:

https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-server-events-client

If I understand correctly, the 404 returns when the client has failed to respond with a heartbeat before the time out setting, therefore the id passed is invalid.
(HeartbeatInterval =60,IdleTimeout = 180)

Looking at application insights gives up 6 out of 330 fails in an hour:

[404s logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISIUq.png)

Digging into the request, nothing seems untoward:

[Request Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSiNS.png)

Problem is, I cannot see anything on the server throwing errors or missing ids in the reports even though DebugMode and ReturnInnerException are both true. I have run this against a local copy and server with a c# client connected to server events feed and cannot seem to get a 404 to return while observing with fiddler.

Is there a way I can catch these server side and see why they are returning a 404 ? I can only assume something is failing and returning a 404 but it is hidden behind service stacks log handling layer. Is this reported to the logging layer as is it likely to happen regually therefore discarded  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 404 Response in a heartbeat is due to the [subscription no longer existing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/b9d24f113a5ed75b9fc8fef6b811608e6c4f8092/src/ServiceStack/ServerEventsFeature.cs#L286), you can use the `OnHeartbeatInit` callback to inspect each heartbeat, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature
{
    OnHeartbeatInit = req =>
    {
        var subscriptionId = req.QueryString["id"];
        var subscription = req.TryResolve<IServerEvents>().GetSubscriptionInfo(subscriptionId);
        if (subscription == null)
        {
            //... subscription no longer exists
        }
    }
});
```

Which will let you inspect the subscription of 404 heartbeat responses but it wont tell you why the subscription was removed.

You can handle the `OnUnsubscribe` to get a callback when a subscription is unsubscribed which should help identify why the subscription was removed.

To help with debugging you can upgrade to the [latest v5.4.1 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) which now has [embedded pdbs and source-link enabled](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/v5-4-1-now-hosting-source-link-enabled-packages/6728) which will let you easily debug into ServiceStack source code.